# Magento 2 Theme product page

Tags: magento2

I cannot find a simple tutorial for this simple task 'Theme product page'

1. I created a theme
   under `magento/app/design/frontend/elia/tst`
2. in admin **content > configuration** click edit and choose the new theme
3. copy files from `magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\view` to `magento\app\design\frontend\elia\tst\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\view`
4. add a static test string to each file
5. in admin Cache Management, click on Flush Magento Cache
6. Go to product page and reload

Expected result - to see the test string in the browser product page

Actual result -product page didn't changed.

I also tried to change the template directory in the source directory `magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\view` and clear the cache, but still the display didn't change.

So, people will probably mark it as duplicate, or point a link to some lengthy documentation about [Magento 2 tutorial: how to use the new frontend templating system](https://inviqa.com/blog/magento-2-tutorial-how-use-new-front-end-templating-system)

But the bottom line is that I couldn't find ANY WHERE a simple working example of theming a Magento 2 site

BTW each click on the admin/frontend takes 30-60 second on a fresh install (wamp64), is that normal?

Answer (score 1):

Try to run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` and clear you browser cache.

Tell me, please, if it works or not for you.

Comment: I can see the change now, 10x

Answer (score 1):

Run below commands

```
php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Now you can view your changes, if not still then remove **var** folder.